# Adding "Active" class to single page Wordpress site top menu

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function

I have the following code below in my Wordpress "functions.php" file.

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
 if( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
         $classes[] = 'active ';
 }
 return $classes;
 }
```

It adds the class of "active" to my nav item. The problem is that is adds "active" to all my links. The reason it does that is because its a one page layout.

I need to find a way to only have the item I clicked on to say active. Not all of them. That way I can style the active menu item to be a different color than the others.

Is there a way to only add "active" to the link I click on? Any help would be great thanks!

Here is my output:

```
  <ul id="menu-menu-2" class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled" style="touch-action: pan-y;">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-7 active"><a href="http://blacklabrador.wpengine.com/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-46 active"><a href="http://blacklabrador.wpengine.com/#the-black-labrador">The Black Labrador</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-47 active"><a href="http://blacklabrador.wpengine.com/#charleys">Charley’s</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-48 active"><a href="http://blacklabrador.wpengine.com/#private-events">Private Events</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-49 active"><a href="http://blacklabrador.wpengine.com/#hungry-gallery">Gallery</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-50 active"><a href="http://blacklabrador.wpengine.com/#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: You'll need JavaScript for that, not php. You need to look at [`on.('click');`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, i figured that. I just need help on implementing it into something that will go with the code above.